# Can't apply ChromaKey filter macOS using GPUImage in AVPlayer

Tags: swift, macos, swift3

I am trying to find a use of **[GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)** library in one of my **macOS** projects. I have a video playing via AVPlayer with AVPlayerItem.

**I need to transform the green background into transparent**.

After 3 days of trying, I can not achieve it.

-I have tried **GPUImageChromaKeyFilter**, but it didn't work. It didn't remove Green Background.

-After that I've added **GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter**, which works but only with a second image, in my case I can not use it, I have also tried with a transparent image and I got a black background.

I would really appreciate your help in this situation.

Please find the code below.

```
import GPUImage

var movieFile: GPUImageMovie!
var chromaKeyfilter: GPUImageChromaKeyFilter!
var blendFilter:GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter!
var inputImage: GPUImagePicture!
var filterView: GPUImageView!

 func initializePlayer(){
    player = AVPlayer.init()
    /* AlpaBlend
     */
    blendFilter = GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter()
    blendFilter.mix = 1.0

    /* ChromaKey
     */
    chromaKeyfilter = GPUImageChromaKeyFilter()

    /* ImagePicture
     */
    let blendImageName = "transparent.png"
    let imgC = NSImage.init(named: blendImageName)

    inputImage = GPUImagePicture.init(image: imgC)
    inputImage.processImage()

    inputImage.addTarget(blendFilter)
    chromaKeyfilter.addTarget(blendFilter)

    /* Player
     */
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video1", ofType: "mp4")
    let sampleURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: path!)

    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: sampleURL)
    player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)

    /* ImageMovie
     */
    movieFile = GPUImageMovie.init(playerItem: playerItem)
    movieFile.runBenchmark = true
    movieFile.playAtActualSpeed = true
    movieFile.addTarget(chromaKeyfilter)

    /* ImageView (videoView)
     */
    filterView = GPUImageView.init(frame: self.container.bounds)
    self.view.addSubview(filterView)
    filterView.setBackgroundColorRed(0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
    blendFilter.addTarget(filterView)
    movieFile.startProcessing()
    self.player.play()
}
```

Please find attached [transparent.png](http://i68.tinypic.com/6sticw.png) file if needed.

Comment: Babiq a bone zgjidhje?

Comment: Jo veq solucion :(

Comment: ska zgjidhje babo